# Sublime Text 2 Ant Build Target: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: ant, sublimetext2

When I run the basic Ant Build from Sublime Text 2 (Ctrl+B), it works, but it runs all targets. I want to specify/override the default build target. I added a new build system like:

```
{
    "cmd": ["ant", "my_target"]
}
```

But it fails with:

```
[Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[Finished]
```

Whats wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The sublimetext [buildsystems documentation page](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/build_systems.html) show how you can make a special case to execute "ant.bat" instead of "ant" on Windows. See the section "Platform-specific Options":

> The windows, osx and linux elements let you provide platform-specific
>   data in the build system. Here’s an example:
>
> ```
> {
>     "cmd": ["ant"],
>     "file_regex": "^ *\\[javac\\] (.+):([0-9]+):() (.*)$",
>     "working_dir": "${project_path:${folder}}",
>     "selector": "source.java",
>
>     "windows":
>     {
>         "cmd": ["ant.bat"]
>     } 
> }
> ```
>
> In this case, ant will be executed for every platform except Windows,
>   where ant.bat will be used instead.

Does that help?

Comment: Fixed the same problem I was just having. Thanks!