# Issue setting up Python IDE in Sublime Text 2. ERROR: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: python, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I want to set up a complete Python IDE in Sublime Text 2. I found the following threads on Stack Overflow that looked helpful:

[How do I run Python code from Sublime Text 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8551735/how-do-i-run-python-code-from-sublime-text-2)

[Running python in Sublime Text 2 getting error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22467699/running-python-in-sublime-text-2-getting-error)

**The Problem**

But I followed those steps and still it didn't work for me. I called my file Test2 and saved it to my Downloads folder. I then entered a simple line of code

```
print 'test'
```

and that returned this error

```
[Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[cmd:  [u'python', u'-u', u'C:\\Users\\Stan Shunpike\\Downloads\\Test2.py']]
[dir:  C:\Users\Stan Shunpike\Downloads]
[path: C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;c:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;c:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Elm Platform\0.14\bin;C:\Users\Stan Shunpike\AppData\Roaming\npm]
[Finished]
```

**Question**

Why isn't this working and what steps can I take to fix this so I can code using python?

**Remark:**

These threads look related, but they don't discuss my problem specifically:

[Sublime Text 2 Ant Build Target: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10925547/sublime-text-2-ant-build-target-error-2-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-speci)

[Can't resolve WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8155945/cant-resolve-windowserror-error-2-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified)

**Remark:**

This thread looked useful

[How to run code in Sublime text 2 python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24235241/how-to-run-code-in-sublime-text-2-python)

But I didn't know what it meant to edit the "sublime build", particularly as I have yet to successfully write any code in Sublime and it looked to me like the thread was asking me to enter code to be executed.

**EDIT 1:**

I had already modified the Environmental Variable path, BUT I had not restarted Sublime. So at MattDMo suggested I did this. When I restarted it, I got the following error instead:

```
  File "C:\Users\Stan Shunpike\Downloads\Test2.py", line 1
    print "test"
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have the path to your Python executable in your `PATH`, so Sublime can't find `python`. Add `C:\Python27` (if that is where Python is installed) to your `PATH` environment variable, then restart Sublime and try again.

Comment: I edited the question to add new info based on the results from doing your suggestion.

Comment: @StanShunpike are you using Python 3? If so, remember that `print` is a function in Py3 - run `print("test")` instead.

Comment: Brilliant! That was successful. Thanks for the help!